Task Scheduler to stop service
I like to make task triggered by service state (Running) to stop the service. stopping part is fixed and working with scheduled task triggered 3min after system start up to run batch file:
@echo off
sc stop "wuauserv"
sc config "wuauserv" start= disabled

so everything to this point works, but I noticed that service is started by something again, so I tried looking for how to setup a trigger by service state Running, and I found here that it is possible to trigger On Event > setting > custom > XML. I added the code as second triger, but XML does not seemd to do anything. maybe my code is wrong? the code:
    <QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System"> 
         *[EventData[Data[@Name='param1'] and (Data='Windows Update')]] 
         and
         *[EventData[Data[@Name='param2'] and (Data='Running')]] 
       </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>

XML is not working and for XML part I need help with
I also tried wuauserv instead of Windows update, also running and Running. system language ENG, Win10 Pro 22H2

What is your end goal? Are you trying to disable Windows Updates? What research have you done regarding stopping a running service using a scheduled task?

to stop service from starting and running, I did ton of research and almost nothing seems to work, I mean I'm at the point were I have a task to stop and disable it after startup, but even then I noticed something still manages to start it

"almost nothing seems to work". We need to know every thing you've tried, otherwise, you're asking us to duplicate the work you've already done, wasting your time as well as ours. Please EDIT your post to add the specific things you've tried, but also... Are you trying to disable Windows Update entirely, or just stop the service for some other purpose, that is the question I asked you earlier and that you have not yet answered.
